# How to create if statement of something that is being echo'ed

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to have a input which changes a value in a database and if it is pressed I want another input to pop up to be able to change the value in the database back.

I have googled a bunch. Have found nothing. Have tried reaching out to classmates but nothing worked

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="aanvraag" id="input2" value="Taxi aanvragen" />
</form>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['aanvraag'])){ 
      if (mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE klant SET aanvraag='1' WHERE username='$uname'")) {                         
          echo "<input type='submit' name='annuleer' id='input2' value='Annuleer taxi'/>";
          echo "Uw aanvraag is verzonden";
      } else {
          echo "error =". mysqli_error($conn);
      }
  }    
  if(isset($_POST['annuleer'])){ 
      if (mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE klant SET aanvraag='0' WHERE username='$uname'")) {
          echo "Uw Taxi is geanuleerd";
      } else {
          echo "error =". mysqli_error($conn);
      }
```

Comment: Can't really get the whole picture from the snippet you provided, What is the current behaviour vs. expected?

Comment: He just want another input field after "aanvraag" is submitted he want input field with "annuleer" and if this is submit he want to run second if condition with post,  Am I right?

Comment: That's what i thought looking at it. But, that's assuming the opening form tag goes to the correct place. If it is breaking at that point, or is it breaking when the input is returned? as it is not wrapped in a form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    $showfirst=true;
    if(isset($_POST['annuleer'])){
        $showfirst=true;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['aanvraag'])){
        $showfirst=false;
    }




    ?>


<form action="" method="post"> 
    <?php 
    if($showfirst){
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="aanvraag" id="input2" value="Taxi aanvragen"/>
        <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="aanvraag" id="input1" value="Taxi aanvragen"/>
    <?php
        }
    ?>

</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['aanvraag'])){ 
        if (mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE klant SET aanvraag='1' WHERE username='$uname'")) {                         
        echo "<input type='submit' name='annuleer' id='input2' value='Annuleer taxi'/>";
        echo "Uw aanvraag is verzonden";
        } else {
            echo "error =". mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }    
    if(isset($_POST['annuleer'])){ 
        if (mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE klant SET aanvraag='0' WHERE username='$uname'")) {
            echo "Uw Taxi is geanuleerd";
        } else {
            echo "error =". mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
```